TypeScript error: “Property 'Router' does not exist on type 'typeof import("express")'” in Express routes
I’m developing a Node.js/Express application in TypeScript and keep running into the following compile-time error in VS Code:
Property 'Router' does not exist on type 'typeof import("express")'.
It appears whenever I try to import Express and create a router. For example:
import * as express from 'express';
const router = express.Router(); // TS2339 error
I’ve tried switching to a default import (import express from 'express';) and removing the .default references, but the error still persists. Sometimes I also see “Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof import("express")'.”
What did you try and what were you expecting?

Checked my tsconfig.json: I confirmed "esModuleInterop": true and "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true are both set to true.
Ensured dependencies: I installed express@^4.21.2, @types/express@^4.17.21, and also removed any references to @types/express-serve-static-core that might conflict.
Removed/Reinstalled modules: I deleted node_modules and reinstalled everything from scratch to clear any potential mismatched version conflicts.
Restarted VS Code: Attempted to clear the TypeScript server cache.

Despite all this, I still see the TS2339 error, and I can’t get TypeScript to recognize express.Router(). I would expect the above code to compile normally and allow me to create an Express router.
How can I resolve this TypeScript error so that express.Router() (and similar Express imports) are recognized correctly?
Edit
Thanks for the follow-up! I can confirm that tsc fails both locally and in GitHub Actions. Here's the error log from GitHub Actions when I run npm run build (which calls tsc):
Error: src/domain/auth/auth.routes.ts(12,24): error TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof import("express")'.
Error: src/domain/care-team/care-team.routes.ts(13,24): error TS2339: Property 'Router' does not exist on type 'typeof import("express")'.
Error: src/domain/document/document.routes.ts(7,24): error TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof import("express")'.
Error: src/domain/patient/patient.routes.ts(11,24): error TS2339: Property 'Router' does not exist on type 'typeof import("express")'.
Error: src/domain/routes.ts(12,29): error TS2339: Property 'Router' does not exist on type 'typeof import("express")'.
Error: src/index.ts(14,36): error TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof import("express")'.
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

I also get similar errors in VS Code’s Problems panel. Here’s my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"],
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

What I’ve tried

Migrated from import * as express from 'express' to import express from 'express'.

This fixed the “Property 'default' does not exist” errors but introduced “Property 'Router' does not exist” errors.


Removed references to express.default.Router().

Now the code looks like const router = express.Router();, but tsc still complains about Router not existing.


Checked dependencies and types:

express is at ^4.21.2.
@types/express is at ^4.17.21.
@types/express-serve-static-core is not explicitly in package.json.


Cleared and reinstalled:

Removed node_modules, reinstalled, and even pinned my @types/express version with "resolutions": { "@types/express": "4.17.21" } to no avail.


Searched for a conflicting type definition:

Verified there’s no local express.d.ts in ./src/types.
Searched for any unusual declare module 'express' overrides—found none.



Actual vs. Expected
I would expect import express from 'express'; followed by const router = express.Router(); to compile without errors, but instead, TypeScript complains:
TS2339: Property 'Router' does not exist on type 'typeof import("express")'.

Does anyone know what might override or conflict with the standard Express types or how to debug further?

I cannot reproduce this with either Express v4 or v5. Do you actually get the error when running tsc or is it only VSCode complaining? Please [edit] your question to include your tsconfig.json

I'd try import express, { Router } from 'express' but what you have should work (and does for me in a quick test). Perhaps you shouldn't exclude node_modules?
